# How can i edit existing A record using Python Boto in Amazon Route 53

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-route53

I am using boto with Route 53

I can add the A record with

```
changes = ResourceRecordSets(conn, "ZZZZZZZZZZ")
change = changes.add_change("CREATE", "test.MYDOMAIN.com", "A")
change.add_value("7.7.7.7")
result = changes.commit()
```

Is there any way that if i already have `test.mydomain.com` and i want to change its A record

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: It seems there is an UPSERT directive. This is kind of an old answer, may be UPSERT was not available at the time of writing. If it is available, it would be best to use it.

I believe the only actions available are 'CREATE' and 'DELETE' so you would have to delete it first then do a create.

Comment: i also thought the same but with delete i first need to get the old A record and then update with new one. is there any way to get the A record with boto

Comment: @user22 The function `get_all_rrsets` should help. Its listed in [boto api](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/route53.html)

Comment: `-1`, this answer is incorrect. You should perform an [`UPSERT`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/route53.html#boto.route53.record.ResourceRecordSets.add_change) also shown [here](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/route53_tut.html#updating-a-record). @kostas-demiris has the actual correct answer and should be accepted as such.

Comment: @Urda Thank you for pointing out why you downvoted. I have edited my original answer.

Comment: @Parag thank you for correcting it, I've restored my upvote for you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of CREATE use UPSERT

```
change = changes.add_change("UPSERT", "test.MYDOMAIN.com", "A")
```